# iphone email attachment and application handleOpenURL

Tags: iphone, email

I want to send/receive attachments with Mail iPhone, and pass those attachments to my App.

If I send a normal link like:

```
myApp://someurlehere/withOneParam
```

my apps open and the event handleOpenURL fires.

But I don't know how to change the name of the attachment to go like this way:

```
[pickerMail addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"myApp://backup.xml"];
```

When I receive the e-mail attachment, the name is:

```
myApp:__backup.xml
```

Should I encode/decode with Base64 ot the URL or something like that ?

thanks in advance,

r.

Comment: I found a similiar question here:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180074/can-i-set-my-iphone-app-to-run-when-a-user-opens-an-e-mail-attachment

It seems that now this is impossible, I hope I'm totally wrong here ... :-)

Comment: Instead of using an attachment, I get the contents of the file and once it's encoded, I put them in the setMessageBody, but It's always truncated, the link it's only until the ?

myApp://localhost/backup?PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZG...

Only this is underlined and act as a link, and it's the url passed:
myApp://localhost/backup

still figurating how passing data between two remote devices ...

thanks,

r.